# SMTP Attack on server

Tags: security, email, iis, smtp

I have an IIS7 web server at Rackspace that is being utilized/attacked in some manner to send SPAM. I have run several variations of anti-virus and malware software on the server and cleaned anything found, but it is still happening.

I'm leaning towards some kind of web form attack, but there are several sites on this server and I didn't create all of them, so figuring out what form(s) is being used (or even where they all are) is proving challenging.

Does anyone know of any solution to pinpoint what script(s) might be firing off these emails? Is there any way to monitor the SMTP service with more information? I've looked at SMTP logs, but all I see are things like:

2014-02-14 06:00:52 127.0.0.1 [---server info, etc---] SMTPSVC1 [-compname-] 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<--------@-------------------> 250 0 56 43 0 SMTP - - - -

In fact, there are 19,608 in about a 16 hour period in this one log file I'm looking at. But unfortunately, this doesn't seem helpful.

If anyone could offer any insight, that'd be great!

Comment: Are the emails all coming from the same address?

Comment: Those all say the same FROM address ... usually, there are a few different TO address. I think that is why I'm leaning towards a form attack. I've searched for that address in the entire file system and haven't found it. If that address is in some database somewhere, I'm not sure how I'd find it.

Comment: So is the FROM address really <--------@-------------------> or did you change it to dashes for privacy reasons?

Comment: I changed to the dashes - the domain is a client. The full address is DoNotReply@---client domain---

Comment: ...and that address (DoNotReply@) does not exist.

Comment: Make sure your set to local relay only, not open relay.

Comment: I've actually tested for open relay with these: mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx mailradar.com/openrelay spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/shopenrelaytest.php ... and had a co-worker test it with telnet. Don't believe open relay is the problem. I should have mentioned that in original question, sorry.

Comment: How about checking your web server logs, to see if there is one particular script that is getting hit a lot.  If so, that may be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, you have a webpage that has been compromised (which is what I think you suspect), and is being used to generate all the messages. The webpage probably accepts a FROM and a TO, without any validation.

If you start seeing these come in, as a test, start shutting off websites, until you see the attack stop.

Then, start the website back up, see if it continues. Then, I would start grepping that website location for files relating to email.

Comment: I marked this correct as this is close to what I've done to solve (I hope) the problem. First, I shut down IIS entirely and the attack stopped. I restarted IIS and turned off sites that seemed most likely culprits and eventually found the one. Then, I just started removing folders until I narrowed it down to the css folder (of all places). There I found a strange PHP file. Removing it seems to have stopped the attack. No Joomla sites on this server, but I found this guy with the same problem: 

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?294510-Suspicious-%93sys0972500-1-php%94-inside-httpdocs

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server is configured to act as an email relay server, which allows anyone to send email that is in transit to your server for your server to send on (relay).  Spammers do this to cover up the original origination point of the email.

The fix is to configure your server not to be a relay server.  More background info here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

Comment: I've actually tested for open relay with these: 
http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx
http://www.mailradar.com/openrelay/
http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/shopenrelaytest.php

... and had a co-worker test it with telnet. Don't believe open relay is the problem. I should have mentioned that in original question, sorry.